# LibGdx - Change actor texture when I click him

Tags: textures, libgdx, actor

I'm new in Libgdx and I'm stuck in changing the texture of my actor when I click him.
My game is about a character who throws balls to break a wall.
I have the character created "stand up" in my game and I want him to change the texture (with an animation may be... I have 3 more textures of he doing a move) when he throws a ball. Then, he has to get back to his default texture up again.
is it possible?
Sorry for my english. It´s my first post. Thanks

Comment: Without any code there is not much we can do here...

Answer (score 1):

Is your player a custom class that extends `Actor`?

If so, you could simply add a listener (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#wiki-event-system) for it to receive click events. The animation itself can be done using `SpriteAnimation` (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation) or by some custom `Action` (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#wiki-actions).

Hope this helps... :)